# Flutter app is crashing although I wrote it in try catch block

Tags: flutter, dart, try-catch

I am using Firebase Auth for my app and for login and to handle errors I wrote it in a try-catch block, but when I enter an incorrect password the app just crashes and throws *"PlatformException (PlatformException(ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD, The password is invalid or the user does not have a password., null))"* this error.

**How can I fix this?**

Here is the code, and the same is for registering users.

```
try {
    final newUser = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    if (newUser != null) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
    }
    } catch (e) {
        print(e);
    }
```

Comment: Do you use vscode and have "all exceptions" enabled? https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/29642168/56313186-38641e80-610f-11e9-858f-862ceac5c818.PNG

Comment: Are you certain that the exception is being thrown by the code within the `try` block?

Comment: @gugge that was the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the solution with VSCode's "All Exceptions" didn't work for you...

Keep in mind that the **debug** version may throw exceptions while the same code in a **release** version may not.

If you are sure that your code is failing within the `try` block and you are handling the `catch` correctly (like OP is), then try running your app with `flutter run --release` and check to see if it works.

Check this question/answer here for a bit more information: [Flutter catching all unhandled exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879455/flutter-catching-all-unhandled-exceptions)