# Why flutter procedure not crash?

Tags: flutter, dart

When an app contains flutter code. The flutter code will never cause app crash. But the swift or java code can cause app crash. Some article explain that swift and java are multithread but dart is single thread. So why multithread will lead to crash but single thread will not.

Comment: This would suggest that flutter can indeed crash. What are you basing this on? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879455/flutter-catching-all-unhandled-exceptions

Comment: First of all, we are not propagating our error to the native part. Flutter is just a UI layer running on top of the native APIs . So if something bad happens on the UI Layer that thing stays there as flutter is running totally on its own isolate(Thread). And also flutter is built more into catching errors rather than crashing the App.